Hutchinson's Notation in Fractals and Self-Similarity
I have been examining https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~john/Assets/Research%20Papers/fractals_self-similarity.pdf for my thesis but couldn't find an explanation for two notations in the paper. Particularly I'm curious about the hashmark (U+23) in the lower index of $S_{i}$ on page 2 and the right angle symbol (U+221F) on the following page in the same section. Does anyone know what they are supposed to mean?

Can you please add some screenshots to your post?  What does "U+###" mean?

In any event, both notations are defined on page 6.

@XanderHenderson Thanks, I didn't notice that because I thought the explanation should be before the first usage, and I wasn't reading the whole document. Btw, U+ is the Unicode for the symbol.

A lot of authors will present the major results of their paper at the front, and then work up to them throughout the paper. This means that they might include a lot of as-yet undefined notation.  Hutchinson's paper is in that style.
